# Xcode: Is it possible to build in command line exactly as in GUI?

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode project that I myself did not author. It has a multi-stage build sequence that is not trivial. For the purposes of static-analysis I am attempting to build it from command line using xcode build. However, the command line invocation produces errors in the build that the GUI build does not.

Is there a sure-fire way to get an Xcode project to build exactly as it did in the command line as in the GUI?

I would be wonderful is there was a way to export an XCODEBUILD invocation from the GUI that covered all the build phases. Is this possible?

I am using an invocation like:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "PROJECT.xcworkspace" -scheme "MY SCHEME NAME" -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -configuration Debug
```

Comment: what are the errors that are procuded by the invocation of xcodebuild? Can you paste the complete line you try to run?

Comment: There are literally thousands of errors ;) I'm trying to focus on getting the same invocation as what XCODE does. I added a sample invocation.

Comment: Try with a destination flag, `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Retina'`

Comment: Sadly, this does not change the result.

Comment: I'd suggest you paste the build output somewhere we could see the errors, would be easier to help you in this situation